# node-redis-retry-strategy package is not working and I'm not able to limit number of reconnections and delay between every reconnection

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, redis-server

I've setup a Redis caching and for that I've a Redis-server running on wsl2 and client on NodeJS platform. As soon as the redis-server went down I've to make a few connections that too with a waiting time, but it's making reconnection requests continuously even if I'm using this package(node-redis-retry-strategy).

Here's my code

```
const redis = require('redis');
var retryStrategy = require("node-redis-retry-strategy");

var client = redis.createClient({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 6379,
    retry_strategy: retryStrategy()
});

client.connect()

client.on("connect", function(){
   console.log("connected to redis server !!!")

client.on("reconnecting",function(){
    console.log("inside reconnecting")
})

client.on("error",function(error ){ 
    console.log(error)
})
```

And also I've tried sending option argument

```
const redis = require('redis');
var retryStrategy = require("node-redis-retry-strategy");

var client = redis.createClient({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 6379,
    retry_strategy: retryStrategy({
        allow_to_start_without_connection: true,
        number_of_retry_attempts: 7,
        delay_of_retry_attempts: 1000
    })
});

client.connect()

client.on("connect", function(){
   console.log("connected to redis server !!!")

client.on("reconnecting",function(){
    console.log("inside reconnecting")
})

client.on("error",function(error ){ 
    console.log(error)
})
```

And the versions for redis and the retrystrategy package I'm using is

```
"redis": "^4.3.1",
"node-redis-retry-strategy": "^2.1.1",
```

additional data

node version v16.17.1

for setting redis-server locally I've used : v=7.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.2.1 bits=64 build=68bf11aad5b039df

And I'm using WSL2

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 4.4.0 and was looking for auto reconnect solution.
And it looks like there is no such option, so it appears to be  not supported.
[image: redis options]

So what I've done is just setting up reconnection by hand

```
protected handleRedisConnected = () => {
    this.log("redis connection established");
    this.reconnectionAttempt = 0;
};

protected handleRedisDisconnected = () => {
    this.log(`redis connection is down, reconnecting #${this.reconnectionAttempt}`);
    setTimeout(this.initRedis, this.reconnectionAttempt++ > 11 ? 11 : this.reconnectionAttempt * 5000 + 5000);
};

private initRedis = async () => {
    this.log("initializing redis client");
    try {
        this.redis = createClient({url: this.redisUrl});

        this.redis.on("connect", this.handleRedisConnected);
        this.redis.on("error", this.handleRedisDisconnected);

        await this.redis.connect();
        this.log("initializing redis client success");
    } catch (error) {
        this.logError(`initializing redis client failure ${error}`);
        this.handleRedisDisconnected();
    }
};
```